# Can't import ghostscript

Tags: python, import, python-3.x, ghostscript

I use Python 3.3.  Just downloaded and installed ghostscript 32 bit (GPL release), but I can't import it.

I'm using the command:

```
import ghostscript
```

and I receive the error:

```
ImportError: No module named ghostscript
```

I tried it with capital 'G', still doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: How have you installed the package? What OS are you using?

Comment: To remove doubt, the module name is `ghostscript`; all lowercase. Reference: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ghostscript

Comment: @bernie I'm using Windows 7.  I ran the .exe file for Windows 32 bit from here: http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html  and it installed successfully.

Comment: That is the actual Ghostscript program. In order to have a programmatic Python interface to said program you also need to install the ghostscript Python package from PyPI. The link to said package is in one of my previous comments. Best of luck to you.

Comment: You installed command line program. Why do you expect to be able to import it in Python? Even if you download Python interface module from pypi, you won't be able to use it on Python 3.3

Answer (score 5):

You need to not inly install Ghostscript, but also install the Python module. Download it from here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ghostscript and unpack the file, and run `python setup.py install`

This module is not reported to work with Python 3, so you'll probably have to use Python 2. Also it's untested on Windows.

Comment: FYI, it was really easy for me to make it work for me with python3. all I had to do was run the python2 to python3 conversion tool 2to3 on the install directory: "2to3 -w /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ghostscript/"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by copying the ghostscript repo under the file which you imported the package. But as ghostscript is written in python2, and you are using python 3, you need to fix some errors. For example:

```
no module named _gsprint under __init__.py
```

(fixed by updating the "`import _gsprint as gs`" to `from . import _gsprint as gs`).

Thanks

Comment: FYI, it was really easy for me to make it work for me with python3. all I had to do was run the python2 to python3 conversion tool 2to3 on the install directory: "2to3 -w /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ghostscript/"